# Django/BooleanField: how to add space between case and label?

Tags: css, django, forms

I have a django project
I have an models with a booleanField -> checkbox in the form

But I don't know why the checkbox is sticked to the label.

I try to select the html element to add specific css but the 2 elements move together...

current result:  [ ]I have read... (the 2 elements are sticked)

expected result: [ ]......I have read...

models.py

```
class Aveugle(models.Model):
    unb_ide = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unb_val = models.BooleanField("I have read ITBM procedure and want to unblind treatment", null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
unb_val = forms.BooleanField(label = _("I have read ITBM procedure and want to unblind treatment"))
```

Comment: unb_val = forms.BooleanField(label = _(" I have read ITBM procedure and want to unblind treatment"))
notice the blank before "I"

Comment: no, I already try that but does'nt work...

Comment: Use css where css is required. ```input[type="checkbox"] + label { 
  margin-left:30px;
}```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
&nbsp;
```

This is a temporary solution, but it's just a patch, you need to handle css and html better to make it more solid.